# How to return custom view for http error response in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

How Can I define custom View files for each of http error responses and then ask laravel to send that view file automatically to user when I'm returning an http error response in my application?

Comment: You mean return error code then Laravel return appropriate your custom View?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you can define a page for every HTTP error code and put it in `resources/views/errors/`

So, if you want to create a view for a 404 HTTP response you should create the view:

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```

and Laravel will redirect automatically your users to the specific view

Additionally, you can customize the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class that is responsable for rendering errors from exceptions: the  `render` method is called everytime an `Exception` rises, so you can intercept the `HttpException` generated by the HTTP error and redirect wherever you want:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    //if $e is an HttpException
    if ($e instanceof HttpException ) {

        //get the status code 
        $status = $e->getStatusCode() ;

        //if status code is 501 redirect to custom view
        if( $status == 501 )
            return response()->view('my.custom.view', [], 501);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: Can I send 501 error from my controller like this: return response()->view('my.custom.view', [], 501);

Comment: @Salar : Yes, but using the `render` method of the `Handler` will make it automatic: every time a 501 error rises inside the APP the `render` method is triggered and the view will be show along with the status code. In your case you are returning the view manually passing the status code

Comment: Don't forget to specify namespace for HttpException: use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

Answer (score 0):

First in `.env` file
change  `APP_DEBUG=true` to  `APP_DEBUG=false`
Second create your custom file and rename to `404.balde.php` and copy to

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```